# How can I find most recently changed row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains audit related records. There is a column which stores the approval status with value 'N' and 'Y'. I have to find the record which was recently changed from approve status 'Y' to 'N'.

Sample data:

```
Request_No    approve_status request_create_date          audit_no_in
22866         N              2016-06-21 11:47:12.7530000  1016
22866         N              2016-06-21 11:46:52.3660000  1015
22866         Y              2016-06-21 11:46:13.9290000  1014
22866         Y              2016-06-21 11:45:14.3200000  1013
22866         N              2016-06-21 11:37:27.9410000  1012
22866         Y              2016-06-21 11:37:03.4510000  1011
22866         N              2016-06-21 11:32:29.6310000  1010
22866         Y              2016-06-21 11:31:41.0270000  1009
22866         N              2016-06-20 19:17:30.4820000  1008
22866         N              2016-06-20 19:14:30.4720000  1007
22866         Y              2016-06-02 13:12:53.5170000  1006
```

Required output:

```
Request_No    approve_status request_create_date          audit_no_in
22866         N              2016-06-21 11:46:52.3660000  1015
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`LEAD()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) and [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) together:

```
SELECT p.request_no,p.approve_status,p.request_create_date,p.audit_no_in
FROM(
    SELECT s.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.request_no ORDER BY s.request_create_date DESC) as rnk
    FROM ( 
        SELECT t.*,
               LEAD(t.approve_status,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY t.request_no ORDER BY t.request_create_date DESC) as last_status
        FROM YourTable t) s
    WHERE s.approve_status = 'Y' AND s.last_status = 'N') p
WHERE p.rnk = 1
```

The first inner query select the last status, the second one filter those who didn't change from `Y` to `N` and ranks them base on their dates, the third one filter only the newest change.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Just a minor edit-- SELECT s.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.request_no ORDER BY s.request_create_date DESC) as rnk

Answer (score 0):

I use another way to find the result you want. Just search a recently  'Y' record where has a 'N' record updated. Also, if your database engine version is 2008, it still can process.

SQL :

```
select * from Table1 where audit_no_in = (
select Max(audit_no_in) + 1 
from Table1 
where approve_status ='Y' 
and audit_no_in < (select max(audit_no_in) from Table1 where approve_status ='N'))
```